# c++ xerces reference without define but is defined

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, xerces

I follow the instructions for [build xerces in linux](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/build-3.html)
    ./configure
    make
    make install

But I'm trying to run the first example from [Programming Guide](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/program-3.html)

```
#include <xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp>
// Other include files, declarations, and non-Xerces-C++ initializations.

using namespace xercesc;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try {
    XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();
  }
  catch (const XMLException& toCatch) {
    // Do your failure processing here
    return 1;
  }

  // Do your actual work with Xerces-C++ here.

  XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate();

  // Other terminations and cleanup.
  return 0;
}
```

But I'm getting a few errors:

```
 === Build: Debug in vasprun_xml (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===

    vasprun_xml/main.cpp|22|reference to  `xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgXercescDefaultLocale' not define

    vasprun_xml/main.cpp 22reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize(char const*, char const*, xercesc_3_1::PanicHandler*, xercesc_3_1::MemoryManager*)' not define
```

How can I solve this issues?

Comment: Sounds like you're not linking with the xerces libraries.  Show your compile/link command(s).

Comment: I put build output in this pastebin http://pastebin.com/Bdcn9E1R . If is useful I'm using code::blocks

Comment: Oh! You have reason the problem is that Code::Blocks not auto detect system dynamic library. We need go to Project->Build Options->Linker Settings and than add the the name of your library (in our case xerces-c-3.1) without lib  prefix. Ok and than build and run without erros. Is like do g++ -o main main.cpp /path-to-your-lib/src/.libs/libxerces-c-3.1.so

Comment: If you have found the answer to your own question please post it here as an answer, and then accept it, so that the question becomes closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anon Mail has reason.

The problem is that **Code::Blocks** not auto detect system dynamic library.

We need go to

> Project->Build Options->Linker Settings

and than add the the name of your library (in our case **xerces-c-3.1**) without lib prefix. Ok and than build and run without erros.

Is like do

> g++ -o main main.cpp /path-to-your-lib/src/.libs/libxerces-c-3.1.so